# How to convert iso 8601 to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Tags: linux, unix

**I would like to compare date with hwclock.**

*HW Clock Reading*

```
$ hwtime=$(hwclock -r | rev | cut -d"." -f2- | rev)
$ echo $hwtime
// Wed 01 Nov 2017 02:36:59 PM ICT
```

*System Clock Reading*

```
$ date +%c 
// Wed 01 Nov 2017 03:10:48 PM ICT
```

*Example seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC*

```
$ date +%s
// 1509522055
```

*Question*

**How to convert the $hwtime to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC?**

 
To compare like this.

```
if [ $hwclock_in_second -ge $systime_in_second ];
then
    break
fi
```

Comment: what linux do you use?

Comment: please, don't edit my answer, add a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

maybe there are straiter ways, but this seems to work :

```
date --date="$(hwclock -u)" +%s
```

**EDIT**:

seems that:

```
date --date="$(hwclock -r | rev | cut -d"." -f2- | rev | cut -d" " -f2-)" +%s
```

was necessary for it to work on the questioner's box. For some reason I don't have the problem on my box. Please feel free to add comment if you have suggestions about the "why".

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html). You might use the `-d` or `--date` option to  [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) to parse some other date. You might use the `%s` format to get a [Unix-epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) based time in seconds.

Read also about [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html) and [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). You generally should not change the system time abruptly.

See also [difftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/difftime.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html), [localtime_r(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime_r.3.html), [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) for programs in C.